# Как получить значение с тега <select> из файла формата .ftl в FreeMarker

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, freemarker

Пытаюсь получить значение с тега, однако получаю `null`.

```
<select name="categoryName">
    <#list categories as category>
    <option name="category">${category.categoryName}</option>
    </#list>
</select>
```

**Вот контроллер:**

```
@Autowired
public Servicem service;

@Autowired
public CatService catService;

@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(){
    return "hello";
}

@GetMapping("/articles")
public String getAllArticles(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("articles",service.getArticles());
    return "articleslist";
}

@GetMapping("/article/{id}")
public String getArticle(@PathVariable("id") int id,Model model){
    model.addAttribute("article",service.getArticle(id));
    return "showArticle";
}

@GetMapping("/addArticle")
public String getArticlePage(Model model){
model.addAttribute("categories", catService.getArticles());
    return "createArticlePage";
}

@PostMapping("/addArticle")
public String addArticle(@ModelAttribute("article") Article article){
    service.addAndUpdate(article);
    return "redirect:/articles";
}

@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteArticle(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    service.delete(id);
    return "redirect:/articles";
    }

@GetMapping("/update/{id}")
public String update(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("article", service.getArticle(id));
    return "editArticle";
}

@PostMapping("/updateArticle")
public String updateArticle(@ModelAttribute("article")Article article) {
    service.addAndUpdate(article);
    return "redirect:/article/" + article.getId();
}
```

Comment: Каким образом вы получаете значения?

Comment: С тега form : `<form name="article" action="/addArticle" method="POST">` с обычных инпутов данные доходят, а вот на select выбрасывает исключение: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Comment: Тут надо смотреть какой констрейнт срабатывает.

Comment: Ниже он и пишет что колонка 'category' не может быть null. Я сразу и писал что на этом теге все обрывается

Comment: где такая колонка находится, чтобы ее можно было посмотреть?

Comment: `private int id;
 private String name;
 private Date date;
 private String text;
 private String category;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас название колонки отличается от названия на форме, поэтому надо переименовать название поля

```
@Getter @Setter
private String categoryName;
```

Comment: Ты прав, блен, с сервлетами было по проще , спасибо